# ffmpeg return different result on different OS

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I use following command to stream an online video link

```
ffmpeg -i "source link" -c copy -t 20 output.mkv
```

It worked well on my win10 PC, then a few days ago, I tried this on a new PC with Ubuntu installed,it returned following error

```
Error parsing AAC extradata, unable to determine samplerate
```

If I omit "-c copy" in the command, it worked on Ubuntu, but the output video is re-encoded which is not my requirement.

Does anybody know how to make Ubuntu do the same as win10?

Comment: Is the version of ffmpeg identical?

Comment: The versions of FFmpeg are likely different. Try reinstalling identical versions on both OSes and run the command again.

Comment: Not only the versions may be different, but they may be compiled with different options and libraries

Comment: Thanks @pigeonburger, I checked my ffmpeg version on ubuntu, it was an old version(although I updated ffmpeg before use) since my ubuntu was not the latest, so I upgraded my ubuntu and updated ffmpeg again, the error disappeared